# Pandas: How to append a single row to a pickled and zipped dataframe efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I'm in a situation where I have to add a single row to the end of dataframe very frequently. Initially I used plain text `.csv` files and therefore appending a line at the end of the file was trivial and didn't require loading the dataframe to RAM.

```
line_to_add = '1,2,3\n'
with open('path/to/file.csv', 'a') as file_handle:
    file_handle.write(line_to_add)
```

For memory disk reasons I would like to save my dataframe as a pickled+zipped file, but if I do that I loose the ability to easily append to the end of the file. Is this doable without having to load the dataframe into RAM every time?

Comment: Genuine question, does zipping a pickle actually reduce size?? In reference to your question: I don't think you can do what you're trying to do.. I'm assuming the file is too big to be efficient? Why don't you look at a database? If you want to keep it local/simple I'd look at sqlite

Comment: In the tests that I have run, zipping a pickled file does reduce its size by quite a bit, 3x in my case. Pandas actually has a compression argument when using `.to_pickle`. 
After thinking about it it makes no sense to append a single line at a time to a zip file, it won't be able to compress anything with only 1 line of information. Regarding the idea of using a database instead, although I have not tested it, I'm concerned that it wouldn't solve my main issue which is disk memory space, as from my understanding a DB like Postgres might actually allocate more memory per row than a text file.

Comment: Good to know about the zipping! I think a database will be the best option. You're worried about disk memory so maybe look into a hosted solution? AWS, Azure, etc. The only other solution I can think of is your zip folder containing pickled series (an individual row) that you then could read in and concat(). I wouldn't encourage that though..